# Windows Forms Application C# button on click close specific form

Tags: c#, windows, forms

i am doing school project and its my first time using visual studio ,here is a small explanation...!

have log in,form, after click on button -log in- it leads me to main form with 4 buttons  where i can go to 3 other forms and exit ...problem is that i need only to make some interactive exe file that will guide professor trough
my system  (need to show him how my app will look like)..have some programming experience,and know how to pop-up some form on click ...main problem is that i don't know how to close that 1. log in form after i come to main form  trough log in button or how to make program with next and back buttons

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `this.Close();` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

give each form a Specific **Tag** then

```
class CloseTagedForm
 {
        public void ZatvoriTagovanuFormu(string myTag)
        {
        for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)//when you have to change the items you should do a reverse loop !
            if (Application.OpenForms[i].Tag != null && Application.OpenForms[i].Tag.ToString() == myTag)
                Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
        }
 }
```

you can close any form from any place in your code

Comment: still little confused ...i know that 1. part of your code will pop up some other form on click , in my case main form and declare tag ,and other part i import in that main form on button ?

Comment: you want to close your window from inside itself or from another form

Comment: sorry for bad English ...i got some error so i am confused ..where do i need to put CloseTagedForm method?

Comment: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/f5j31 tell me what is wrong getting error on FOREACH :(

Comment: sorry you can't modify an object inside foreach loop, so UPDATED MY CODE

Comment: It'll work for sure after seeing your screenshot, i've tried it myself this time

Comment: hahahah with this code when i click button it opens 24 or 25 clone forms this is not for closing the last one used   :D

Comment: no just replace the second code **for** instead of **foreach** that's why i put **UPDATED**, the other code's meaningless